# How to alter django settings based on current request?

Tags: django

I'm running multiple sites from a single django instance, and expect the framework to eventually serve several hundred sites from one or several installations.

I need to patch some django settings based on the current request. I've written some middleware to monkey patch the settings, but I need these settings to be patched before the middleware gets invoked because other apps aren't taking the monkey-patched changes (i.e. apps get run then middleware gets run so the apps don't use the monkey-patched settings).

I should also add this is mainly for the benefit of third-party apps that I haven't written, so I don't want to go round adding decorators or anything like that because that would mess up my upgrade path.

So:

- How can I get access to the current request in an app's **init**.py file?
- Will an app's **init**.py get called once per request or only once? If it's only once, how else could I do this so I can manipulate the settings once per request?
- Is it safe to do this kind of monkey patching? I know it makes code a bit more opaque, but I don't want to use different wsgi files per site because I want to allow users to edit some of these settings and have my monkey patching come from the database.
- Is there a better solution that would allow certain settings to be stored in the database?

Comment: Why don't you generate WSGI files from database? That seems like much saner approach to me.

Comment: Interesting. But I was thinking that in terms of scalability it'd be better if the whole app was site agnostic so I can just provision a new server, deploy my code and each server would just serve pages for whichever site it gets requests for.

Comment: When you say monkey patching are you modifying `django.conf.settings` in your middleware?

Answer (score 5):

This module - django-tupperware does what you are asking about: https://bitbucket.org/jiaaro/django-tupperware/
Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

**Never ever ever** change settings on the fly. You cannot predict how the application may one day be deployed, and in most of them the project will fail in.. interesting ways.

Comment: So what alternatives do I have? I need to get settings from the database and have them applied before other apps get called.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't even attempt it. Put more planning into the architecture instead.

Comment: Well, the whole point of the application is that users can create their own sites and store some settings in the database... What would you suggest?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same thing @Paul . I tried rewriting a database.py file ( which in turn gets imported as a module to settings.py ). The behaviour is erratic on production. 2 out of 4 times, the old database settings gets picked. Solution: restart the server - but how in production? :(

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer and should be a comment!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have hundreds of sites which will be dynamically reconfigured all the time, you might try to Djangos [django/conf/__init__.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/__init__.py) which is used to supply the settings to the rest of the framework. You might be able to alter it in a way it depends on the request and it's Host field. Or you'll get many interesting failures at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to give each request, ALL the settings and update them on the fly with a middleware, how do i do this? 
Is rather simple:
This is the middleware that does it all

```
from django.conf import settings

class DumpObject: pass

class Settings(object):
    def process_request(self,request):
        request.settings = DumpObject()
        for setting in dir(settings):
            if not setting.startswith('__'):
                setattr(request.settings, setting, getattr(settings,setting))
```

The DumpObject is just there so i can use the object.property notation, it could have been a dictionary, but i wanted to keep some similarity in the syntax.
This assumes that none of your settings name starts with __ which is a fair assumption.
So if i want to override a particular setting, i don't keep a settings file i do it in this middleware. like this:

```
class Settings(object):
    def process_request(self,request):
        request.settings = DumpObject()
        for setting in dir(settings):
            if not setting.startswith('__'):
                setattr(request.settings, setting, getattr(settings,setting))

         if 'mydomain' in str(request.host): #this is thanks to django-hosts project
            request.settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID = '89298393-238'
```

Of course this doesnt take into account the problem of accessing the settings the old way
    from django.conf import settings

```
settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID = 'the value in settings.py'
```

But it really doesn't matter because you will probably only want to change the settings on the context of having a request object, available.